# how to use not between clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I don't know what wrong with this query. I am getting error. Can please any one tell me about this.

```
$this->db->where("ac.booking_date", $booking_date); 
$this->db->where(''.$booking_date .' NOT BETWEEN ac.booking_date AND ac.end_date', null, false);
```

> ## A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '10:00 NOT BETWEEN ac.booking_date AND ac.end_date ORDER BY `ac`.`id` DESC' at line 7
>
> SELECT `ac`.*, `p`.`first_name`, `p`.`last_name` FROM `anb_crm_bookings` `ac` LEFT JOIN `anb_crm_users_personal_info` `p` ON `p`.`user_id` = `ac`.`created_by` WHERE `ac`.`email` = 'devid00@Gmail.com' AND `ac`.`record_id` = '36841' AND `ac`.`booking_date` = '2019-05-29 10:00' AND 2019-05-29 10:00 NOT BETWEEN ac.booking_date AND ac.end_date ORDER BY `ac`.`id` DESC
>
> Filename: models/BookingModel.php
>
> Line Number: 245

Comment: Logically if you are comparing `booking_date` with your input date, then what is the use of second where statement?

Comment: `$this->db->where(" "'.$booking_date .'" NOT BETWEEN ac.booking_date AND ac.end_date", null, false);` Correct this

Comment: i need to check previous booking like if privious us 10:00 to 12:00 so next must not between this like 11:00 to 1:00.

Comment: Please update your question with better clarification or logic you want, because from what we see, you ain't wrote anything

Comment: format your date first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're forgetting quotes in the 2nd WHERE.
   Replace it with the following code

```
 $this->db->where("ac.booking_date", $booking_date); 
 $this->db->where('"'.$booking_date .'" NOT BETWEEN ac.booking_date AND ac.end_date', null, false);
```

Comment: or simply: `$this->db->where("$booking_date NOT BETWEEN ac.booking_date AND ac.end_date", null, false);`

Comment: why you need betwean? just use '> < and ='

Comment: @Vickel can I use date function with ac.booking or ac.end_date to extract only time.

Comment: yes, in select write
`DATE_FORMAT(ac.booking,'%H:%i:%s')`

Comment: @Akshay you should ask a new question on that matter, anyway here is some info: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/between-and/